# Type System attributes : Developing intuition and Addressing Misconceptions

Tags: dynamic, types, type-conversion, type-theory

A **type system** is a set of rules used to provide additional layer of information about entities in a program, so that the runtime, or the compiler, or any other piece of machinery, knows what to do with the strings of bits it operates on. It also help maintain contracts - the compiler (or code analyser, or runtime, or any other program) can verify that at any given point the program operates on values programmers expect it to operate on.

**Attributes of a programming language, regarding its type system:**

**Type writing attributes:**

-**Explicit / Manifest** (Explicitly typed)
The programmer has to explicitly write down the types, thus the types become manifest in the   source code. 
     Type is associated with variables ( int x = 5-> 5 is int)

-**Implicit / Latent / Inferred** (Implicitly Typed)
The programmer does not write down the types. The types are thus implicit or latent.
     Types is associated with values (x = 9.5 ->9.5 is float)

**Type Safety attributes:**

***Type checking*** is the process of verifying if the program commit any type errors (verifying the type safety of a program).

-**Dynamic** (Dinamically typed)
 Type checking* is carried on at runtime (while program is running -> dynamic)

-**Static**   (Statically Typed)
   Type checking* is carried on before runtime (while program is not running -> static)

***Type safety*** of a  programming language: the extent to which a programming language discourages or prevents type errors.

**-Strongly typed**
A language with stricter typing rules  ( high type safety).
   Very few ways, if any, to bypass the type system.

**-Weakly Typed**
A language with looser typing rules  (low type safety)
    Few ways,or some, to bypass the type system.

**Type compatibility attributes:**

***Compatibility of type A and type B***: A can be used where B can be used, OR, B can be used where A can be used.

***Identity of type A and type B*** : A can be used where B can be used, AND, B can be used where A can be used.

**-Nominal Typing:**
Two types are compatible if they have the same name. (typedef int A ; typedef long long A;...)

-**Structural Typing:**
Two types are compatible if they have the same structure. (typedef char A; typedef char B;...)

**Type logic attributes:**

**-Soundness of a Type System**
It's prevented any type error to occur.
If things aren't allright, they won't be alright.

**-Completness of a Type System**
It's not prevented any non-typerror to not occur.
If things are alright, they will be alright.

**Final Considerations:**

It's important to not confuse a Dynamic language with a Dynamically typed language, or a static language with a statically typed lanaguage.
A Dynamic language is a more general concept. It's a language that can carry on different activities during runtime such as adding new code, extending objects and definitions, or modifying the type system( indeed).
   And the same concept applies to static languages too.

Be careful in associating different attributes,deducing one from the other, or create mental implication between them . The degree of complexity and constant innovations, allow nearly all attributes combinations to be able to coexist (with higher or lower degree, and often in subtle ways).

This is the result of a one week study on type systems, with a background in logic and programming. The aim is to check for my current understanding, and to create a discussion that address once and for all doubts and misconceptions about type attributes.

Comment: There is a lot of misinformation and half-knowledge about type systems on the internet. I suggest reading Pierce's book on Types and Programming Languages for a better understanding. For example, a type system assigns types to *expressions* (or more generally, syntactic phrases) -- that includes both variables and values. Type inference / implicit typing also assigns types to all expressions. OTOH, "latently" typed is not the same as implicitly typed; rather, it is a euphemism for "dynamically typed", which itself is a euphemism for untyped, i.e., expressions have no defined type.